# How to log particular statement using Hugo plugin

Tags: java, android-studio-2.0, hugo-logging

I am using Hugo plugin for logging in my project. As mentioned in the git-hub page, it does logs the method return values, and method param values.

For example:

```
  @DebugLog
public String getName(String first, String last) {
  SystemClock.sleep(15); // Don't ever really do this!
  return first + " " + last;
}
```

will print

```
D/Example: ⇢ getName(first="Jake", last="Wharton")
D/Example: ⇠ getName = "Jake Wharton" [16ms]
```

Is there a way to log the single statement instead of whole method ?

Answer (score 0):

Hugo doesn't log single statements. You can use [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber).